# How to extract information from the following text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract **title, description & address** from text of different websites. I'm currently doing some web crawling which extracts the information stated above. However, I am having trouble coming up with a regular expression that matches to the expected text output that I want below.

Can I know how can I improve my regular expression and embed the suggested **set of rules** to meet and extract the information above?

**My Regex:**

```
(^.+\n)(^.+\n)?(^\d+.*\d{6})
```

**Set of rules to embed:**

```
First line (title)
    - can contain any alphabets and numbers
    - should not contain dot(.)
Second line (description or additonal information)
    - can contain any alphabets and numbers
    - should contain dot(.)
    - second line can be empty
    - if its empty then extract the first line which is the title
Third line (address)
    - address extraction
```

**Input Text:**

```
View store information
TAMPINES MART
11559.33Km Away,
5 TAMPINES ST 32, #01-07/16 TAMPINESS MART, 529284
67817232
Open Now
Full Menu
View store information
THE SIGNATURE
The SIGNATURE is a wonderful destination for shopping text.
51, CHANGI BUSINESS PARK CENTRAL 2, #01-15, THE SIGNATURE, 486066
65883667
Open Now
Full Menu
Jewel Changi Airport
Jewel Changi Airport is a breath-taking place for families text.
78 Airport Boulevard, #B2-275-277 Jewel Changi Airport, Singapore, 819666
```

**Expected Text Output: (Ideally)**

```
TAMPINES MART
11559.33Km Away,
5 TAMPINES ST 32, #01-07/16 TAMPINESS MART, 529284

THE SIGNATURE
11559.97Km Away,
51, CHANGI BUSINESS PARK CENTRAL 2, #01-15, THE SIGNATURE, 486066

Jewel Changi Airport
78 Airport Boulevard, #B2-275-277 Jewel Changi Airport, Singapore, 819666
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to match words using `\w` and repeat the first capturing group to get the value of the last iteration as the title.

```
^(\w+(?: \w+)*\r?\n)*(?:(?![^.\r\n]*\.|.*\d{6}).*\r?\n)*(?:([^\r\n.]*\..*(?:\r?\n(?!.* \d{6}).*)*)\r?\n)?(.* \d{6}(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DO3UMu/1)

```js
const regex = /^(\w+(?: \w+)*\r?\n)*(?:(?![^.\r\n]*\.|.*\d{6}).*\r?\n)*(?:([^\r\n.]*\..*(?:\r?\n(?!.* \d{6}).*)*)\r?\n)?(.* \d{6}(?:\r?\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)$/mg;
const str = `View store information
TAMPINES MART
11559.33Km Away,
5 TAMPINES ST 32, #01-07/16 TAMPINESS MART, 529284
67817232
Open Now
Full Menu
View store information
THE SIGNATURE
The SIGNATURE is a wonderful destination for shopping text.
51, CHANGI BUSINESS PARK CENTRAL 2, #01-15, THE SIGNATURE, 486066
65883667
Open Now
Full Menu
Jewel Changi Airport
Jewel Changi Airport is a breath-taking place for families text.
78 Airport Boulevard, #B2-275-277 Jewel Changi Airport, Singapore, 819666`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log("Title: " + m[1]);
  if (undefined !== m[2]) {
    console.log("Description: " + m[2]);
  }
  console.log("Address: " + m[3]);
  console.log("\n")
}
```

Comment: It's matching everything as whole. Can the regex be changed to extract the title and description seperately instead of everything?

Comment: @scorezel789 Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/PVzYJu/1

Comment: I've edited my Input Text. I did some testing and it does not seem to match group 2 and 3.

Comment: @scorezel789 Perhaps you could use this patten and exclude matching sentences that start with View, Open and Full `^(?!View|Open|Full)([^\W\d]\w*(?: \w+)*)(?:\r?\n(?!\d+).*)*(?:\r?\n(\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Za-z]+ \w+,?))?\r?\n(.* \d{6})$` https://regex101.com/r/UeBT5M/1

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the design seems to be static if I exclude sentences that start with View, Open and Full. When i tried to remove them, I believe the regex will not work.

Comment: Is there a rule to tell distinguish between the title and the parts that start with View etc?

Comment: No. The assumption here is to focus on the two lines after the address match, which is two lines **before** the address which may consist of the `title & description & address` or `title & address only`. Hence, to distinguish the title and description is that the `title` does not have a dot(.) but the `description` does.

Comment: @scorezel789 This would match the values without the negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/BrWkwh/1

Comment: This is almost perfect!! I've tested by removing the **second line** from each of the cases. All the matches works beautifully! It does the job and extracts the `title & address`. But when i add a character to the start of the Group 1 in Match 1, it does not seem to capture the second line text description - which does not necessarily have to start with a number. If it really troubles you then its ok i really appreciate your effort!!!

Comment: @scorezel789 For the second group you might get the following matches asserting that the next line does ends with 6 digits. https://regex101.com/r/RtDayQ/1 But is there a rule for the third group where to stop matching after the 6 digits at the end?

Comment: No there is no rule for the third group to match anything after the 6 digits at the end. Could you take a look at my previous edited comment? Im currently having another issue... sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @scorezel789 Then you can match the whole line if it contains a dot. For the first group I have updated it to allow the match starting with a word char `\w` Perhaps for the third group you can exclude matching lines that start with an upper case char. https://regex101.com/r/JvxWhc/1 It is difficult to differentiate the match between Open, Now, Full Menu or View store information without using it in the pattern without knowing how many sencences may follow

Comment: @scorezel789 I have updated the answer with the latest pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solves of extracting the title, description and address problem. But it still does not solve the fact if the description is not present. Regardless, you are amazing! I will try to figure this out.

Comment: @scorezel789 Ah, like this then https://regex101.com/r/DO3UMu/1

Comment: This is perfect! You are simply badass (:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210124/discussion-between-scorezel789-and-the-fourth-bird).